# underlying code for the node red modules

Tags: node.js, node-red

In node red, each module has a javascript running in background. When I drop in a http module the corresponding javascript is run. (Please correct me if my understanding is wrong).Where would these codes reside? If I want to create a new module by modifying the existing where should i make changes?

Answer (score 3):

node-red is an open source project available on github here: https://github.com/node-red/node-red

The code for the default palette of nodes is here: https://github.com/node-red/node-red/tree/master/nodes/core

If you want to find out more about how to write your own nodes, there as a guide in the documentation here: http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/

If you have any questions, you are best served on the mailing list here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Nick